# Rails DatePicker - Object [object Object] has no method 'datepicker'

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, datepicker

I'm trying to add datepicker to my rails 3.2.8 application.

Since it is rails 3+, I didn't add anything to the application.html.erb.

My application.js is the following:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// the compiled file.
//
// WARNING: THE FIRST BLANK LINE MARKS THE END OF WHAT'S TO BE PROCESSED, ANY BLANK LINE SHOULD
// GO AFTER THE REQUIRES BELOW.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .

$(function(){
    $("#transaction_deadline").datepicker();
});
```

And in views/transactions/_form.html.erb

I have:

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :deadline %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :deadline %>
  </div>
```

But still, datepicker doesn't work and gives:

> TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'datepicker'

error

That would be great if you can help me.

Thanks,

Comment: are you importing jQuery UI library? or at least the datepicker widget?

Comment: Aren't these imported with " <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>" code ?

Comment: I'm asking, are you importing jQuery UI/datepicker along with the jQuery library?

Comment: Yes, I guess with these lines: 
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css", "application" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js", "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js", "application" %>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/213-calendars-revised?view=asciicast) , you should add the datepicker component explicitly both in your application.js and application.css .

In application.js:

```
//= require jquery.ui.datepicker
```

and in application.css:

```
*= require jquery.ui.datepicker
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this gem can help you => https://github.com/joliss/jquery-ui-rails