# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'datepicker'

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, datepicker

This is the error i am facing:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'datepicker' myquery.js:13
(anonymous function) myquery.js:13
fire jquery.js:3049
self.fireWith jquery.js:3161
jQuery.extend.ready jquery.js:434
completed
```

the code of myquery.js is below:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
    });
});
```

In my application.js i have:

```
//= require jquery
//= require myquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

And in my application.html.erb i have this:

```
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" %>
```

true %>

and lastly my index.html.erb says:

```
<label for="date">Date</label>
<input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

i have tried almost all the answers on stackoverflow but no gain. plz tell me what to do...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13351173/rails-datepicker-object-object-object-has-no-method-datepicker
it can help you

Answer (score 1):

You have to load jquery ui first

And then load myquery.js

because **datepicker()** is the method of jquery ui.

So, your javascript load order sholud be the following...

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require myquery
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree
```

Comment: is it //==require jquery_ujs or jquery_uis?

Comment: it is //= require jquery_ujs or you can check the following link

https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs

Answer (score 0):

It seams as `jQuery UI` js file is not loaded before you use `datepicker` method. Change the order of require(jquery_ujs before myquery):

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require myquery
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Answer (score 0):

same require order as write Hasib Hasan Arnab
and

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
  });
});
```